# Numerical Analysis resources

Tags: numerical-methods

What are some of the best sources for a course of Introduction to Numerical Analysis? I am looking for something which will start from basic and goes up to the advanced level.

Books/ Lecture notes/ Video lectures any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512432/recommendations-for-numerical-analysis-texts?rq=1

Comment: I should also add Numerical Methods That Work by Forman Acton

Comment: @Moo,Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommendations for Numerical Analysis texts?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512432/recommendations-for-numerical-analysis-texts)