# Modern book on error analysis in numerical calculations

Tags: numerical-methods

There is a classical book by Wilkinson (
"Rounding Errors in Algebraic Processes"), but reviewer in the Amazon writes:
*Unfortunately, the book discusses these critical topics in terms of 1963 technology. A modern eye finds it jarring to see computer arithmetic described in base 10, when binary is the natural language of machines. Wilkinson discusses fixed-point arithmetic, which is still used heavily in computing for multimedia and embedded systems. His approach is haphazard, though; a more systematic development would have served fixed-point users much better.
In its day, I'm sure this book was current and practical. It's easy to see how the author has distilled more complex discussions into applicable analysis. A lot has happened between that day and this, however. Techniques have developed (and are still being developed), and expository techniques have improved for the topics that the book does cover. **IEEE floating point has since become the standard, and demands discussion of its own.**
The modern reader looking for a practical guide should keep looking.*

Is there a modern book on the same subject, which treats these topics (including IEEE floating point)?

Comment: There are hundreds of books about numerical methods. You could start by looking here, for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512432/recommendations-for-numerical-analysis-texts, https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/book-reference-for-numerical-analysis

Comment: Thank you @hans-lundmark, but I already read these posts. I am looking for modern substitution of Wilkinson's book.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that there is a modern equivalent of Wilkinson's book. You can cover the material with ["Handbook of floating point arithmetic"](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780817647056)  by Muller et. al, ["Accuracy and stability of numerical algorithms"](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898718027?mobileUi=0) by Higham and ["Matrix Algorithms, volume 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0898714141) and ["Matrix Algorithms, volume 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0898715032) by Stewart, but you can safely ignore the reviewer and include Wilkinson's book in your reading list. I find Wilkinson's use of Gershgorin's theorem particularly delightful.