# What are some good Numerical Analysis textbooks?

Tags: numerical-methods

I have been doing some research lately about numerical analysis textbooks, but I have not found anything successfully. I was wondering if there is like some sort of *standard*, for example, whenever someone mentions Calculus, I would think of Spivak or Stewart. I do not have any background nor experience on the subject, so readability counts, and I am a first year undergraduate student. Hopefully I made my point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommendations for Numerical Analysis texts?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512432/recommendations-for-numerical-analysis-texts)

Comment: Yes, it was pretty useful. Thanks