Books on numerical integration
I am looking for a book on numerical integration [ numerical analysis ] that reflects the current state of the art.
I have a copy of Davis and Rabinowitz , but it was written more than 50 years ago.
Even the Second Edition was written 40 years ago.

A MAA review says Davis and Rabinowitz "is still very up-to-date".

That review was in 2010 , @lhf , though I think it will be valid now. I suspect that most newer research within that area is more on tweaking old algorithms , very rarely on making new algorithms.

Somewhat new "Tea Time Numerical Analysis" , last updated in 2021.
Available at https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/textbooks/741
Endre Suli and David Mayers have written "An Introduction to Numerical Analysis" in 2003
Sample chapter available at https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/suli/book.html

More listed at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512432/recommendations-for-numerical-analysis-texts though most are older , maybe not what OP wants.

The book Quadrature Theory by Brass and Petras seems quite modern, but I have no experience with it.
